# How do I print out array values in outside a function it has been modified

Tags: c, arrays, function

```
void sort(int values[], int n);  

void modify_all_aray_values_to_0(int value[], int array_size);

int main(void)
{
    int aray[] = {4,2,56,2,1,7,20,9,3,5,6,4,3,2,44,57};
    int size_of_aray = sizeof(aray)/sizeof(aray[0]);
    sort(aray, size_of_aray);
    printf("\n");
}

void sort(int values[], int n)
{
    // TODO: implement a sorting algorithm
    int temporary;
    //assumes temporary array size will not exceed 1000
    int temporary_array[1000];
    int size_of_tmp_array = sizeof(temporary_array)/sizeof(temporary_array[0]);
    //set all values in temporary array to 0
    modify_all_aray_values_to_0(temporary_array, size_of_tmp_array);
    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        //store the values of values[] i'th in temporary variable
        //at this stage, temporary = 4, because first element in values[] is 4
        temporary = values[i];
        //store result of temporary_array[4]+1 in temporary_array[4]
        //at this stage temporary_array[4],s values is 0
        //when i assigned it, it gets the value (0) and increment it with 1
        //this means so far i have seen value 4 once in values[]
        /*so if this loops again and it found value 4, it will
        modify and increment temporary_array value to 2*/
        temporary_array[temporary] = temporary_array[temporary]+1;
        //so at the end of the loop
        //temporary_array[1] = 1
        //temporary_array[2] = 3
        //temporary_array[3] = 2
        //temporary_array[4] = 2 and so on...
    }
    int tu;
    //print all values in values[] before it get modified
    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        printf("%i-", values[i]);
    }
    printf("\n");
    //assumes it wont loop more than 100 times
    for(int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
    {
        if(temporary_array[i] > 0)
        {
            for(tu = 0; 0 < temporary_array[i]; tu++ )
            {
                //modify valeus[] by assigning i'th value
                //at this stage if when temporary_array[1] is greater than 0
                //store 1 in values[0]
                values[tu] = i;
                //immediately decrease temporary_array[1] by 1
                //now temporary_array[1] is now 0
                //next time the loop will check if its greater than 0
                //if so it will modify values[] and store the value
                //else it wont bother and that means 1 doesnt appear in array again
                temporary_array[i] = temporary_array[i]-1;
                //print values[0] inside loop after modification
                printf("%i,", values[tu]);
                //printed 1
                //will print 1,2,2,2,3,3... and so on after compilation
            }
        }
    }
    printf("\n");
    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        //print values[0] outside the previous loop
        printf("%i-", values[i]);
        //this time around it printed 57 instead of 1
        //prints 57-4-2-2-1-7-20... and so on
        //what could have happend?
    }
    printf("\n");
    return;
}

void modify_all_aray_values_to_0(int value[], int array_size)
{
    for(int i = 0; i < array_size; i++)
    {
        value[i] = 0;
    }
}
```

Please help me out with this.
I have posted this question before but it was not OK and understandable, so I decided to delete the question and studied the users comment just to learn from my mistakes so that I'll be able to ask questions that will be understood by us.

I have really practised the code formatting and I thank god for it now that it is better than the previous post I posted.

Comment: Please read [ask] and specially [mcve]. When you ask a question, try telling us what you did and where it goes wrong, what are you expecting to happen, etc.

Comment: Is there a reason why you us `modify_all_aray_values_to_0` instead of `memset`?

Comment: i am not familiar with (memset)

Comment: nothing prevents you to use google and look it up.

Comment: This code is _WAY_ too noisy. What specifically is not happening that you think should be happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am able to spot a lot of problems with your code. First of all, you must definitely read the [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). To give you a few points:

1. Do not put so many comments in code, it makes it hard to understand
2. Use commonly known concepts by their names, so that it is easy for others to understand what you are doing. Like here, from the looks of it, You are trying to implement [Counting Sort](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/counting-sort/)

As for the code, the **main error** that you are facing is due to this code block

```
for(int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
    if(temporary_array[i] > 0)//If the count of a number is > 0
        for(tu = 0; 0 < temporary_array[i]; tu++ ){ //<- ERROR HERE 
            values[tu] = i;
            temporary_array[i] = temporary_array[i]-1;
            printf("%i,", values[tu]);
        }
```

The problem is that you are each time, setting the `values[tu]` to the newly found non-zero item in `temporary_array`. So what happens is that first, you make `values[0]=1` and then again change `values[0]=2` and so on...

I am not pointing out the exact solution to the problem or why are you facing it. Because it is encouraged that you work it out yourself. So go ahead and look at that code block and try to fix it. In case there are more problems with it, you can ask :)

**PS**: This is my edited version of your code, that made it easier for me to interpret

```
#include <stdio.h>

void sort(int values[], int n);  

void modify_all_aray_values_to_0(int value[], int array_size);

int main(void){
    int aray[] = {4,2,56,2,1,7,20,9,3,5,6,4,3,2,44,57};
    int size_of_aray = sizeof(aray)/sizeof(aray[0]);
    sort(aray, size_of_aray);
}

void sort(int values[], int n){
    int temporary;

    int temporary_array[1000];
    int size_of_tmp_array = sizeof(temporary_array)/sizeof(temporary_array[0]);

    modify_all_aray_values_to_0(temporary_array, size_of_tmp_array);
    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++){
        temporary = values[i];
        temporary_array[temporary] = temporary_array[temporary]+1;
    }
    int tu;

    printf("Before getting modified: ");
    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        printf("%i ", values[i]);

    printf("\n\n");


    printf("temporary_array: ");
    for(int i = 0; i < size_of_tmp_array; i++){
        if(temporary_array[i]>0) printf("%d-%i ", i,temporary_array[i]);
    }
    printf("\n\n");

    for(int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
        if(temporary_array[i] > 0)//If the count of a number is > 0
            for(tu = 0; 0 < temporary_array[i]; tu++ ){
                values[tu] = i;
                temporary_array[i] = temporary_array[i]-1;
                printf("%i,", values[tu]);
            }

    printf("\n\nShould be 1 2 2 2 3 3 4 4 5 6 7 9 20 44 56 57");
    printf("\n\nAfter Sorting: ");
    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        printf("%i ", values[i]);

    printf("\n");
    return;
}

void modify_all_aray_values_to_0(int value[], int array_size){
    for(int i = 0; i < array_size; i++) value[i] = 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks
this worked
`for(int i = 0; i < 100; i++) if(temporary_array[i] > 0)//If the count of a number is > 0 for(; 0 < temporary_array[i]; tu++ ){ //<- ERROR HERE values[tu] = i; temporary_array[i] = temporary_array[i]-1; printf("%i,", values[tu]); }`